# GSL Monte Carlo integration function uses what random generator? how do I change the seed?

Tags: random, gsl, montecarlo

Thanks in advance for the help. I could find no documentation on the site concerning what random number generator the GSL monte carlo integration functions uses. The reason I want to know is that I run my program multiple times expecting a different result but getting the exact same values each time. Is there an easy way to change the seed for the random number generator?

Fred

Answer (score 2):

Here are the [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-number-generator-algorithms.html) for the available generators. 
[This bit in the docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-number-generator-initialization.html) describes how to change the seed.

```
int gsl_monte_plain_integrate (gsl_monte_function * f, const double xl[], 
                               const double xu[], size_t dim, size_t calls, 
                               gsl_rng * r, gsl_monte_plain_state * s, double * result, double * abserr)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
                               Here it is.
```